# How to read data from azure blob storage with BlobServiceClient without downloading rather by using BytesIO stream

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, bytesio

I don't want to get any downloads just get stream of data which I can read using Pandas later

```
>! the parameters of BlobServiceClient are correctly provided
BSC= BlobServiceClient() 
self.stream = BytesIO()
BSC.get_blob_client(
            self.container, self.filename
        ).download_blob(offset=0).readinto(self.stream)
```

Actually I want replcaement for this below code which is using older version of azure-storage-blob

```
self.servivce = BlockBLobService()
self.stream = BytesIO()
self.service.get_blob_to_stream(self.container, self.filename, self.stream)
self.stream.seek(0)
wrapper = TextIOWrapper(self.stream, encoding="utf-8")
return wrapper
```

Comment: Your code contradicts your title. A BytesIO object is not a stream but just a file-like object over a memory buffer. How do you intend to use this?

Comment: Indeed I  just found this piece of code to give a refrence of which packages I am using. Cause I didn't wanted someone to give answer using older version of Azure-storage-blob

Comment: I have updated the question with more detail

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.storagestreamdownloader?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-storagestreamdownloader-content-as-text):

```
io.StringIO(
  BSC.get_blob_client(self.container, self.filename).content_as_text())
```